# Small drone recomendation

Tags: drone

I'm looking for tiny drone for taking some pictures/video while traveling.
At least image quality should be pretty decent. 720 for video would be fine. 
Flying time of couple of minutes will be fine. No preferences for altitude/distance. And it should be allowed to be taken on the plane.

(Not sure what else to include here as don't really use drones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [$60 kit](https://www.opsbuya.com/products/2020-new-2.4g-wifi-luggage-mini-folding-rc-drone-hd-1080p-camera?variant=15435458) (FOB Destination) or drone, battery, charger, controller, and miscellany packs up into an included hardcase 8.3" x 5.2" x 2.6", which fits in an overhead luggage bin of even commuter aircraft. The battery is well under commercial airline regulation limits. It provides 1080P video and the drone's video records on iOS or Android smartphones.

[image: Folding drone in its case]

Comment: HI I understand the video is sent to thesmartphone real time?